# Why my linux account only belongs to one group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts, user-groups

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04, and my username is abcxyz (not real, changed for the matter of the question). If I look at the contents of `/etc/groups`, my user appears in many groups:

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep abcxyz
adm:x:4:syslog,abcxyz,admin
cdrom:x:24:abcxyz
sudo:x:27:abcxyz,admin
dip:x:30:abcxyz
plugdev:x:46:abcxyz
lpadmin:x:113:abcxyz,admin
abcxyz:x:1000:
sambashare:x:128:abcxyz,admin
libvirtd:x:134:abcxyz,admin
libvirt:x:134:abcxyz,admin
docker:x:1002:abcxyz
```

However, when I execute `groups` as my user, I only see:

```
$ groups
abcxyz
```

I have already logout and logged back in, restarted computer, and try modifying the group the user belongs to with `usermod -a -G`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It is: I am a member of the docker group, for example, but I cannot access the `/var/run/docker.sock` file despite having the correct user permissions. Same for files of group I belong to that have read access.

Comment: possible answer there (that would be a bug with lightdm and kwallet): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458194/missing-groups-at-each-startup/458523#458523 . might even be considered to mark it as "having a answer" if that's really the same. affects ubuntu 16 and 18 as well as a few others unrelated distributions

Comment: @A.B effectively, that seems to be the issue. After changing to gdm, the groups started appearing. Please, write it as an answer, so I can mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, so to be considered probably fixed in a few weeks or a few months, triggered *apparently* only with a specific interaction between the *graphical* login [`lightdm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lightdm) and the PAM plugin [`libpam-kwallet5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libpam-kwallet5) and/or `libpam-kwallet4`. From reports seen, it appears to be at least present in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, possibly on other unrelated distributions. I'd rather put a lot of "it appears" because the actual root cause might not be well understood.

To know it's really this issue: login either on console, using `su - $USER` or `ssh localhost` would all set correctly the missing supplementary groups. Chaining several `sg` or `newgrp` with any group available in the output of `id -nG $USER` would also add one by one the missing groups from the configured supplementary groups list.

To work around this (I couldn't actually test it):

- change graphical login manager. [`GDM`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gdm3) is known to work correctly,
- or [disable the offending part of the KDE Wallet PAM integration in `lightdm`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418). Given the role of KDE Wallet it might possibly affect the way some stored secrets are accessible:

  Comment out any line in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` having `auth optional pam_kwallet.so` or `auth optional pam_kwallet5.so`, eg as root with:

  ```
    cp -ai /etc/pam.d/lightdm /root/pam-lightdm.orig && sed -E -i 's/^(\s*auth\s+optional\s+pam_kwallet)/#\1/' /etc/pam.d/lightdm
  ```
- or use any other login method like described above,
- or wait enough time an update fixes the bug.

Credits where it belongs to:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458194/missing-groups-at-each-startup

Probably related:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457884/empty-user-groups-in-terminal-wrapper-applications

Other reference:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1581495

Comment: Flawless explanation. After changing to gdm, the missing groups started appearing. Thank you!